# Electron webview new-window event returning `about:blank` as Url

Tags: javascript, electron

I have a Electron based browser like application which uses Electron's  tag to render client urls. I have my own custom tabs setup using multiple webview tags.

As mentioned in the electron documents, I was using the `new-window` event to handle page requests to open urls in a new tab. It could be requested by window.open or an external link like `<a target='_blank'>`.

My code which was working fine in most cases when the url is specified and not dynamically added later on.

```
const webview = document.querySelector('webview')

webview.addEventListener('new-window', (e) => {
  const url = e.url;
  // used url to render new tabs.
})
```

Lately i have a client login url which when loaded has a button. The button does not have an anchor tag and no predefined urls specified. When opened in chrome, the button click leads to external link opening in a completely new window. The new window briefly shows 'about:blank' in the url bar but then redirects to the actual url.
When i tried to intercept the same external url using `new-window` event in my electron webview, the event returned url which was `about:blank` and i couldn't access the redirected url. Has anybody else faced the same issue ?

Comment: Maybe you could do something with `webview.addEventListener('did-stop-loading', loadstop)` instead of immediatly looking for the url? [Reference](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag)

Comment: I just tested this and it seems to work fine and give me the correct url. I tested here: [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_a_target). Can you try it out with that website?

Comment: I have edited my question a bit. The link you tested works fine in my case too but my problem is a bit different. The target url in my case is somehow only being added after the button is clicked and it opens in a new window.  The new window briefly shows "about:blank" and then redirects to a different url. My new-window event however is triggered immediately after the button is clicked so the url i get is "about:blank". @Elias

Comment: I'm not able to test this due I have no website currently in mind that takes a bit time to load. Are you in any shape or form able to provide the website you need to access?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Any updates so far?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was able to find the eventually-opened url by adding a `will-navigate` listener for the popup window's web-contents:

```
app.on("web-contents-created", (webContentsCreatedEvent, contents)=>{
    contents.on("will-navigate", function(e, reqUrl) {
        console.log(`Popup is navigating to: ${reqUrl}`);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a BrowserWindow and I solved by using the `nativeWindowOpen` flag (experimental at this time)

It is also available for `webviews`

https://electronjs.org/docs/all#using-chromes-windowopen-implementation

Comment: While this may help OP, it's better to add more details, explanation, examples, etc.  And include the essential part of the link here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found some workaround, so want to share.
It's a bit unreliable, but works for my purposes.

Firstly, I caught `'cursor-changed'` event, got needed URL as `lastViewedURL` and saved for later

```
let lastViewedURL = "";
main.webContents.on('cursor-changed', (type) =>
{
  if (type == 'pointer') 
  {
    let code = ` 
    try {
      document.querySelector('#docs-linkbubble-link-text').innerHTML;
    } catch (error) { console.error(error);  }` ;
    
    try {
      main.webContents.executeJavaScript(code)
      .then((result)=> {
        lastViewedURL = result
    })
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }
}  )
```

Then used it, if current url in `'new-window'` event is `'about:blank'`

```
main.webContents.on('new-window', (event, url) => {
  let urlToOpen = url == 'about:blank' ? lastViewedURLInDocs : url;
  shell.openExternal(urlToOpen); 
  event.preventDefault()
})
```